# How do I sum up video game scores for multiple students in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 columns of data.  Column 1 is the student's name and Column 2 is the name of the game they played.  There are 10 possible games that they can play, and are simply titled Game 1 thru Game 10'.  Column 3 contains the score that the student got on the game and it may be positive or negative.  A student may play any of the 10 games 0 times to multiple times (no limits).  Each time a student plays any game, a row of data is created.

I want to sum up all of the scores a student received on any of the 10 games, ordered by students.  Thus, the row headers would be the student names, and the column headers would be the name of the game (Game 1 thru Game 10).

Here's my code to what I had been doing:

```
SELECT [STUDENT],

SUM ( [SCORE]) 
FROM [Students].[dbo].GameScores
WHERE [GAME] = 'GAME 1'  --swap in the game name that you want

GROUP BY [STUDENT]
```

I ran the above code 10 times for each of the 10 games, swapping out Game 1 for Game 2, then Game 3, and so on.  Then I would manually cut & paste the results into Excel as necessary.  As the number of Games get larger (to 100) I obviously don't want to run the above code to manually extract sums of scores for all 100 games.

How do I alter the above query so that I can iterate thru all 10 games (or any X number of games, maybe X would equal 100) and display the results so that row headers are student names, the column headers are Game names, and the cells have the sum of the student's scores for a particular game (this can be either negative or positive).

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You're going to need to add `[GAME]` to your query, and then you're going to need to [PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[sql-server]pivot) the result.  Tons of info here about pivoting.  Or you could let your presentation layer do it for you.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean when you say I need to add [GAME] to my query?  I currently define [GAME] in my query and I don't know how to iterate thru all 10 games or any X number of games (where X can equal 100).

Comment: Start with `SELECT GAME,STUDENT,SUM(SCORE) from ... GROUP BY GAME,STUDENT`.  That will get you the content you're looking for.  If you want to query a subset of your games, just add them to your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT student, [Game 1], [Game 2], [Game 3]
FROM Students.dbo.GameScores g
PIVOT (SUM(Score) FOR Game IN ([Game 1], [Game 2], [Game 3])) pvt
```

You can add game 4 to 10 to the example to satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (student varchar(24), score int, Gametitle varchar(20))
    insert into #temp (student , score , Gametitle )
    values
    ('Student1', 100, 'Game1')
    ,('Student1', 90, 'Game2')
    ,('Student1', 80, 'Game3')
    ,('Student2', 100, 'Game1')
    ,('Student2', 100, 'Game2')
    ,('Student2', 100, 'Game3')
    ,('Student3', 100, 'Game1')
    ,('Student3', 50, 'Game4')
    ; 

select 
    student 
    ,[Game1], [Game2], [Game3],[Game4]




from 
#temp


pivot (

    sum(score)
        for Gametitle in ([Game1], [Game2], [Game3],[Game4])) as pivottable

        drop table #temp
```

Results look like

```
student |   Game1|  Game2|  Game3|  Game4|
Student1|   100  |    90 |    80 |   NULL|
Student2|   100  |   100 |    100|   NULL|
Student3|   100  |   NULL|   NULL|   50  |
```

if for some reason you dont want to type out all of the game titles out try this

```
create table #temp (student varchar(24), score int, Gametitle varchar(20), league varchar(20))
insert into #temp (student , score , Gametitle,league )
values
('Student1', 100, 'Game1','silver')
,('Student1', 90, 'Game2','silver')
,('Student1', 80, 'Game3','silver')
,('Student2', 100, 'Game1','silver')
,('Student2', 100, 'Game2','silver')
,('Student2', 100, 'Game3','silver')
,('Student3', 100, 'Game1','silver')
,('Student3', 50, 'Game4','silver')
,('Student1', 50, 'Game1','silver')


; 

declare @columns nvarchar(max)

select @columns = Coalesce(@columns + ',['+ [Gametitle]+']', '[' + [Gametitle] +']') 
                from (select distinct Gametitle from #temp) columns
                order by Gametitle

declare @query nvarchar (max)

set @query ='
select 

     *



from 
#temp


pivot (

    sum(score)
        for Gametitle in (' + @columns + '))pv



        '

        exec sp_executesql @query

        drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to convert vertical table into the horizontal one. The solution for this is **PIVOT** defined explicit or implicit.

In case when you want the query to be fully dynamic (not to add new games to the query, but the query will take the by itself) you will need to use the dynamic SQL which will analyse your data and prepare the pivot query including all fields, something as below:

```
/* parameters' definition and initializing */
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @columns nvarchar(max);
set @columns = '';

/* Get the unique list of played games */
select @columns = columns + quotename(Game) + ','
from
(
    select distinct Game
    from Students.dbo.Games        
) x
order by Game; /* this will place the payed games in the alphabetical order */

set @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns) - 1); /* to remove last coma */

/* Preparing dynamic SQL based on the played games */
set @sql = 'SELECT student, ' + @columns'
FROM Students.dbo.GameScores g
PIVOT (SUM(Score) FOR Game IN (' + @columns + ')) pvt';

/* Executing the dynamic SQL */
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```